# Просторечие ли слово "просрочка"

Tags: просторечия

Является ли просторечием слово "просрочка" в значении пропущенный платеж по кредиту? Вопрос возник, т.к. есть банковский термин "просроченная задолженность"

Answer (score 2):

Это явно не просторечие, можно обсуждать разве что отнесение к разговорному стилю.
Но словари дают без помет, так что скорее всего следует признать общелитературным.
Что касается наличия банковского термина, то, во-первых, это не полный синоним, "просрочка" - шире и, во-вторых, сама ситуация наличия профессионального термина никак не свидетельствует о просторечности его бытового синонима.

(+)=====

У меня нет под рукой словаря ("Новый экономический словарь"), на который ссылается статья в Вики. Но если там действительно есть это слово, то все вопросы снимаются автоматичесики.

(++)====

Вот нашел слово в финансовом словаре.
https://www.finversia.ru/finhandbook/findictionary/prosrochka-118
Не знаю уж, насколько этот словарь авторитетен у специалистов, но сам факт включения в него слова "просрочка" показателен. Это не просторечие в любом случае.

Comment: Термин **просрочка** есть и в "Большом юридическом словаре": https://petroleks.ru/dictionaries/dict_big_law16.php

Comment: И в "Гражданском кодексе": _**ГК РФ Статья 405. Просрочка должника**_. http://www.consultant.ru/document/cons_doc_LAW_5142/889b9ba62a0c4dcdb5e39ad2a6ad0a6088c5c7ec/